# Approve SharePoint Permissions Level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-permissions

Just need clarification regarding the "Approve" permissions level.  If we put someone in a Group with Approve level, will they have access to change check out and edit the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, they can change check out and edit the page. In the approve permission level, the permission "Override List Behaviors" and "Edit Items" is checked.

Override List Behaviors:Discard or check in a document which is checked out to another user, and change or override settings which allow users to read/edit only their own items

Edit Items:Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can override checkouts . This table can be useful
[Approve Permission Levels - Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels#list-permissions-and-permission-levels)